# Where do I put backend PHP files on Apache?

Tags: apache2, php

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache.

It seems I should place my web site files in the "/var/www/html" directory.

But then where should I place my backend PHP files?

For example, if I have web site forms that will on submit make a request to a backend PHP file, should I put the PHP file in "/var/www/php" and have, for example, the "/var/www/html/index.html" file form action refer to "../test.php"?

I don't want people in general to have access in the browser to my PHP files, which is why I feel they should be above "/var/www/html", but if that is the web root, how can "../test.php" work?

Answer (score 5):

Generally PHP files are meant to be accessed by the general public.  For example, index.php resides in /var/www/html and handles all requests for "/".  If your app file is test.php, then try placing it in /var/www/html/test.php and you can browse to it directly.

As long as you have mod-php5 loaded and enabled, apache will execute that script instead of returning the source code.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, what if my PHP files will have database information, such as tables, columns, maybe even MySQL user and password info. I want my forms to be able to access those php files, but I don't want the general public to view the contents of those php files.

Comment: As long as you have mod-php5 enabled, the general public will not be able to view the contents of those files.

    sudo a2enmod php5
    sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Okay. But what if people try to execute my php scripts directly, passing in parameters to fool the script into doing something nefarious?

Comment: I guess I could create a directory /var/www/html/php and put my php scripts there.

Comment: :)  That's where proper POST sanitation comes into play!  You need to be very cautious about accepting user input, (in specific, never trust user-provided data!!!)  For example if you have a form element for email, ensure that only valid characters are submitted to that form.  If you detect form tampering, then redirect back to the original form html, optionally with an error back to the user.

Many practices are common to inject a one-time form ID into the original form, and require that hash to be present in the submitted data, otherwise they didn't come from your form!

Comment: Another thing, check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for your form.html.  If it's not present, then the user may be trying to do something nefarious.  

By having them in a subdirectory, the user can still execute them directly by browsing to site.tld/php/form.php.

Comment: Those are great suggestions. Thanks very much. I'm very leery about web site security, seems like there are so many ways to attack my site. Guess I just have to be diligent.

Comment: Ultimately, my best advice is to look into a pre-built framework that handles all these security concerns natively.  Because yes as you stated, there are a LOT of attacks against PHP sites.  (I can't move this conversation into chat unfortunately...)  A well built framework will provide easy form validation and input sanitation checks out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 3):

I put my PHP files in `/usr/share/PROJECT-1.0.1` and symlink `/usr/share/PROJECT -> PROJECT-1.0.1`. Then I create an Apache config file `/etc/apache/sites-available/PROJECT`

```
Alias /project /usr/share/PROJECT/test.php

<Directory /usr/share/PROJECT>
    DirectoryIndex test.php
    Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files test.php>
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Diretory>
```

And add `Include sites-available/PROJECT` to `/etc/apache/sites-available/default`

This way I can add new a version `1.0.2` in `/usr/share/` and when I'm done I just switch the symlink `/usr/share/PROJECT -> PROJECT-1.0.2`

Also nobody can access any files inside that folder except `test.php`

Comment: That's interesting. As I might have many html files with forms that might need to access my various php scripts, I'll have to figure out how to extrapolate your example to that scenario. But thanks, that helps a lot.

Comment: Just keep in mind that your `test.php` will be available as `http://YOURHOST/project` with that `Alias`